# .htaccess Rewrite Rule not affecting GET on page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Sample Code**

Here is a sample of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$                index.php?intro=true [L]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)$      index.php?location=$1&intro=true [L]

RewriteRule ^wedding/?$             wedding.php [L]
RewriteRule ^wedding/([^/]*)$       wedding.php?location=$1 [L]
```

And here is some sample code that is featured on both the `index.php` and `wedding.php` page:

*index.php*:

```
if(!$_GET["location"]) { $location = "London"; } else { $location = ucwords($_GET["location"]); }

[....]

<h1>Ben Pearl, <?php echo $location; ?> Magician</h1>
```

*wedding.php:*

```
if(!$_GET["location"]) { $location = "London"; } else { $location = ucwords($_GET["location"]); }

....

<h1><?php echo $location; ?> Wedding Magician</h1>
```

**What is supposed to happen**

The `$location` string should be effected by the `$_GET` value '`location`'.

**What is happening**

The rewrite is working fine on `index.php`; if a user goes to example.com/home/place, `$location` is replaced by `place`.

However, on every other page (including the page with script pasted above), the string is replaced by "london", implying that the page hasn't received the `$_GET` data and the rewrite rule is not working correctly.

What's stranger is that the exact same code, unaltered, worked fine on my `localhost`.

Comment: For the sake of being 100% certain, have you tried `var_dump($_GET)` at the top of your script to see exactly what is in the `$_GET` array? Then you can say for sure that the location key doesn't exist

Comment: Yes. I placed it before any HTML and it returned `array(0) { }`; on the home page I see `array(2) { ["location"]=> string(6) "place" ["intro"]=> string(4) "true" }`

Comment: And can you post a non-working url / path (`/wedding/...`)?

Comment: Yes I posted that above (`array(0) { }`) (sorry for lack of clarity!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off `Multiviews`, which turns on mod_negotiation's "fuzzy" request URI to file mapping. When mod_negotiation sees `/wedding/` and then it sees that there's a file `/wedding.php`, it'll kick in and send the request directly there, completely bypassing mod_rewrite and your rules.

On top of your htaccess file, add:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

That may also explain why it works for the rewrite to `index.php`, since `/home` doesn't look much like `/index.php` (whereas if you had a `home.php`, mod_negotiation would try to map to that instead).

Comment: +1, you know i've done some serious apache hacking in my time, but i never bothered to look at why i always automatically type `-Multiviews` into my configs. Doubt i'll ever use it in my life, but it's always nice to learn new things :)